# How to use FOUND_ROWS() on multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query which executes without an error, however it does not return the correct number of rows. The same query works when selecting from one table, but not two:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as `total` 
FROM `products` t1 
RIGHT JOIN `homepage` t2 ON `t2`.id = `t1`.id;
```

Answer (score 2):

To get a row count do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `total` 
FROM `products` t1 
RIGHT JOIN `homepage` t2 
ON `t2`.id = `t1`.id;
```

Comment: FOUND_ROWS() works with SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and not restricted to limits. If we don't specify SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in our 1st query that is executed. found_rows() will fail to provide proper count of result available.

Answer (score 0):

Execute this first

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS as `total` FROM `products` t1 RIGHT JOIN `homepage` t2 ON `t2`.id = `t1`.id;

Then Execute

```
`SELECT FOUND_ROWS();` // this will give total no. of rows found in above query.
```

Query 1 you can get data and use them , from Query 2 you can get the total count of results found for query 1

For example

```
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS from abcd limit 20"; 
$query = $this->db->query($sql); 
$result = $query->result_array(); 

$total = 0;
 if(!empty($result)) { 
$sql2 = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total"; 
$query1 = $this->db->query($sql2); 
$row = $query1->row(); 
$total = $row->total; // suppose you get total as 150 
}
```

Comment: how do you combine the two queries?

Comment: You cannot combine two query . execute the 1st query and than execute the 2nd query. This goes well when suppose you want 10 - 20 results at a time and you want total count as well. you can use limit in 1st query to limit the result.

Comment: Then how is executing two separate queries going to do anything

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS from abcd limit 20";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$result = $query->result_array();`



`$total = 0;
if(!empty($result))
{
 $sql2 = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total";
 $query1 = $this->db->query($sql2);
 $row = $query1->row();
 $total = $row->total; // suppose you get total as 150
}`

Comment: And if you just want count of rows and not the result. Than you can go with http://stackoverflow.com/a/29942805/2555647 solution

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments @VivekTankaria. Edit your original post to add any new information.